# Is HTMLBars stable enough to use in production?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have a project that uses Handlebars (not with Ember) and I am interested in moving to HTMLBars. Looking at the repository ReadMe and Googling around it is not clear if this project is stable enough yet to use in production. It is now considered stable? Again I won't be using it with Ember.

Will I have to modify my existing handlebars templates to be used with HTMLBars.

Comment: HTMLBars is extremely stable, though htmlbars and glimmer are tightly intertwined, and glimmer is stable, glimmer 2 is about to hit beta in the next few months.  I'd just do a small conversion and see how well you can convert, if you can convert, the tech itself is stable.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll want to use HTMLBars on a standalone project, as it is very tied to Ember.js itself.